# $k$ points in hyperbolic $n$-space lie in a hyperbolic $(k-1)$-subspace

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $k > 1$ be an integer with $k \leq n$. Consider $k$ points inside hyperbolic $n$-space $\mathbb{H}^n(R)$ for some radius $R > 0$. Prove that these $k$ points lie in fact in a totally geodesic $(k-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{H}^n(R)$, which is isometric to $\mathbb{H}^{k-1}(R)$.

I do not particularly know how to start this exercise. If $k = 2$, then I think the solution is pretty simple, as for $2$ points we can always take the (unique) geodesic between them if they are distinct (if they are equal, then any geodesic through the respective point will do). However, I do not know how to proceed for $k > 2$.

Comment: What representation of $\Bbb H^n(\Bbb R)$ are you working with?

Comment: I am not sure it is relevant, but we can take the hyperboloid model for simplicity (all models are isometric).

Comment: I suggest using the Klein model for this question.

Comment: @Magma In the Klein model, the geodesic between two points is the straight line between them. So I think that for $k$ points we take the pairwise geodesics between them and then somehow "fill in" some space between these points, but how do we do this formally?

Comment: How would you do this in euclidean space?

Comment: @Magma I see what you mean: in Euclidean space, for any $k$ points, I would take any $(k-1)$-plane that contains these $k$ points.  So now the question is: is any $(k-1)$ inside the Klein model isometric to the $(k-1)$-dimensional hyperbolic space?

Comment: Yes, any intersection of the unit ball with an affine subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is a flat subspace of $\mathbb H^n$. There are several simple ways to prove this using the fact that geodesics are straight in the model.

Comment: @Magma I am not particularly sure how to prove that the intersection of an affine subspace with $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be isometric to some hyperbolic space; namely, I am not sure how to relate the restricted metric on the affine subspace with the usual hyperbolic metric. Could you please expand more on this detail?

Comment: You don't need to think about metrics. Just consider that any totally geodesic submanifold is locally geodesically convex, and think about what this means in the Klein model where geodesics are straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to like the Lorentzian model of the hyperbolic space, here is a solution using this language (it is equivalent to the one using the Klein model suggested by Magma).

Let $q$ be a nondegenerate quadratic form on $V={\mathbb R}^{n+1}$ of signature $(n,1)$, $H$ a component of $\{v: q(v)=-1\}$ (the one contained in the future light cone). This is your model of the hyperbolic $n$-space. Take your $k$ points $x_1,...,x_{k}\in H$. Then there exists a (generically, but not always, unique) $k$-dimensional linear subspace $W\subset V$ containing these points. Then $W\cap H$ is a hyperbolic subspace of dimension $k-1$ in $H$. In the Lorentzian model, this is just a definition of a hyperbolic subspace. If you do not know this fact, it is a nice exercise in linear algebra to check that the restriction of $q$ to $W$ is again nondegenerate and has signature $(k-1,1)$.